# Can I extract numbers from string without counting the amount of numbers in that string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to extract numbers from string to an array of int, but I could not find appropriate function in Matcher class. Is there any way to do this better way than I? For example such split() function split string by delimiter and return prepared array.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String stringWithNumbers = "1111llalbhahbah2222albhlahbahb3333lHVvlVLH4444ABHABHB";
        int[] numbersFromString;
        
        // find amount of numbers in stringWithNumbers
        Pattern toFindNumbers = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m1 = toFindNumbers.matcher(stringWithNumbers);
        int amountOfNumbers = 0;
        while (m1.find()) amountOfNumbers++;
        
        // fill array with numbers
        numbersFromString = new int[amountOfNumbers];
        m1.reset();
        for (int i = 0; m1.find(); i++)
        {
            numbersFromString[i] = Integer.parseInt(m1.group());
        }
        
        // print array (test)
        for (int i: numbersFromString)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
1111
2222
3333
4444

Comment: You can add the numbers to an `ArrayList` and then convert the `ArrayList` to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `String` method `split` with regex `\\D+` like below:

```
String stringWithNumbers = "1111llalbhahbah2222albhlahbahb3333lHVvlVLH4444ABHABHB";
String[] s = stringWithNumbers.split("\\D+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)); //it will print [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444]
```

Comment: '... to extract numbers from string to an array of int...' OP wants an int array as output

Comment: @Hülya That's easy to convert

Comment: @Abra there is time (10 or 15 minutes) after publishing question when you can not accept answer

Comment: @Hülya I have seen now your message. Your solution is certainly correct and I upvote it, but OP nominated he was looking for something like split() function and in his code it's already present the conversion from string to int.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String stringWithNumbers = "1111llalbhahbah2222albhlahbahb3333lHVvlVLH4444ABHABHB";
int[] numbersFromString = Stream.of(stringWithNumbers.split("[a-zA-Z]+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

for (int i: numbersFromString)
{
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

Output:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```